# Shadow Catcher Compositing Blender 3.4 how?

Tags: compositing-nodes

I've been struggling with the shadow catcher in Blender Cycles for hours now. It's not possible to me to mix the denoised image with the shadow catcher image in the compositor (I assumed it would be a Multiply Mix node). Could anybody tell me the node setup for this issue?

How can something basically necessary be so complicated...

Regards and thanks for any help!

Comment: I luckily found two valuable tutorials how to do it... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=29xoVux9xlY https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PeVyu9DPmUk However I came to the conclusion, that for me it's better and faster to render the Shadow Catcher pass separately and process it in Photoshop.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I use the *Shadow Catcher*, if this is not what you want you have to clarify in the question how you want it to be set up.

Here I have a simple scene with a sphere on a plane. The plane has *Shadow Catcher* enabled under *Object Properties* > *Visibility*. I've disabled the background with *Film* > *Transparent* and I've enabled *Denoise* in the _Render Properties.

[image: shadow catcher setup]

If I now render the scene, I have a denoised image of the sphere with a shadow on a transparent background which I could put over any image/background I like with the *Alpha Over* node:

[image: alpha over]

If you don't want to use the *Denoise* function for the *Render*, you can of course use the *Denoising Data* and the *Denoise* filter in the *Compositor*, but still you can simply overlay the image with the shadow over some background:

[image: compositor denoising]

Comment: Thank you Gordon! I guess this will do the job! In my case I had the problem that I haven't connected the Alpha over node correctly!